# Mysql save PHP array as each value in new field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a PHP array like

```
array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

I need to store this in a MySQL database in a way that each value is inserted into a new field and not in a same field. It can be achieved by using foreach statement and running the query inside foreach statement. But I need a more efficient way to do it in a single query.

Comment: Why must you avoid a for loop?

Comment: 1 query use implode() on the array

Comment: I am trying to avoid loop to speed up the process. Because this array might contain more number of values in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pack multiple records in your INSERT query - produce single one in a loop and then execute it at the end.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (is, name)
VALUES
(0, 'Ford'),
(1, 'BMW'),
(2, 'Volvo)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try it using implode

```
insert into tablename (field1, field2, field3, field4) values('".implode("'", array(...))."');
```

it will produce like:

```
insert into tablename (field1, field2, field3, field4) values('Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  insert multiple records with one SQL query. Read following article:

- [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Also discussed on SO before:

- [Speeding up large numbers of mysql updates and inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952288/speeding-up-large-numbers-of-mysql-updates-and-inserts/3952302#3952302)